# How to get lines between two strings in a file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, file

I would like to get strings between < tur> and < /tur> and create a .xml file named this string. I would like to write  lines between < kitap> and < /kitap> to the .xml file if the string are same between < tur> and < /tur>.

Here is the all File:

```
       <katalog>

<kitap>
    <isim> Elektrik Devreleri Laboratuvarı Deneyleri </isim>
    <yazar> Avni Morgül </yazar>
    <tur> Bilim-Mühendislik </tur>
    <yayınevi> FSM VAKIF ÜNİVERSİTESİ YAYINLARI </yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN> 6058626089 </ISBN>
              <tarih> 2016-08-26  </tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Bilim Tarihi ve Kültür Yazıları</isim>
    <yazar>Prof. Dr. Aykut Kazancıgil , Prof. Dr. Hüsrev Hatemi , Ayhan Vergili</yazar>
    <tur>Bilim-Tarihi</tur>
    <yayınevi>İŞARET YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6750691417</ISBN>
              <tarih>2013-05-03</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Simyacı (Ciltsiz)</isim>
    <yazar>Paulo Coelho</yazar>
    <tur>Edebiyat</tur>
    <yayınevi>CAN YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9750726439</ISBN>
              <tarih>2018-01-22</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim> Genel Coğrafya </isim>
    <yazar> Emin Atasoy  </yazar>
    <tur> Genel-Coğrafya </tur>
    <yayınevi> EZGİ KİTABEVİ  </yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN> 9758606962 </ISBN>
              <tarih> 2010-01-01  </tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim> Araştırma Yöntemleri </isim>
    <yazar> Kemal Kurtuluş   </yazar>
    <tur> Sosyal-Bilimler </tur>
    <yayınevi> TÜRKMEN KİTABEVİ   </yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN> 6054259199 </ISBN>
              <tarih> 2010-01-01  </tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Etkili Uygulama İçin Sosyal Hizmet Araştırması</isim>
    <yazar>Jerry Finn , Judy L. Krysik</yazar>
    <tur>Sosyal-Bilimler</tur>
    <yayınevi>NİKA YAYINEVİ</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6058477612</ISBN>
              <tarih>2015-02-24</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Bilimsel Araştırma Kılavuzu - Projeden Mekaleye</isim>
    <yazar>Kural Gülbahar, Yasemin Gülbahar, Muzaffer Üstdal, Robert Vuillaume</yazar>
    <tur>Sosyal-Bilimler</tur>
    <yayınevi>PELİKAN YAYINLARI </yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9758778287</ISBN>
              <tarih>2004-03-01</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>


<kitap>
    <isim>İlmiyye Salnamesi</isim>
    <yazar>Seyit Ali Kahraman</yazar>
    <tur>Bilim-Tarihi</tur>
    <yayınevi>İŞARET YAYINLARI </yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9753500645</ISBN>
              <tarih>N/A</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Mutlu Evlilik Psikolojisi</isim>
    <yazar>Prof. Dr. Nevzat Tarhan</yazar>
    <tur>Psikoloji</tur>
    <yayınevi>TİMAŞ YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6050822915</ISBN>
              <tarih>2017-11-16</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>İç Sayfalara Gözat Pandanın Başparmağı Doğa Tarihi Üzerine Düşünceler</isim>
    <yazar>Stephen Jay Gould </yazar>
    <tur>Bilim-Tarihi</tur>
    <yayınevi>VERSUS KİTAP</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6055691257</ISBN>
              <tarih>2010-06-04</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Bilim Tarihi ve Kültür Yazıları</isim>
    <yazar>Prof. Dr. Aykut Kazancıgil , Prof. Dr. Hüsrev Hatemi , Ayhan Vergili</yazar>
    <tur>Bilim-Tarihi</tur>
    <yayınevi>İŞARET YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6750691417</ISBN>
              <tarih>2013-05-03</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Kürk Mantolu Madonna</isim>
    <yazar>Sabahattin Ali</yazar>
    <tur>Edebiyat</tur>
    <yayınevi>YAPI KREDİ YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9753638029</ISBN>
              <tarih>2018-01-03</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Simyacı (Ciltsiz)</isim>
    <yazar>Paulo Coelho</yazar>
    <tur>Edebiyat</tur>
    <yayınevi>CAN YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9750726439</ISBN>
              <tarih>2018-01-22</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Aman Piyasalar</isim>
    <yazar>E. Ahmet Tonak</yazar>
    <tur>Ekonomi</tur>
    <yayınevi>KALKEDON YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9944115216</ISBN>
              <tarih>2007-11-09</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Kapitalizm Marksizm ve İslam</isim>
    <yazar>Jacques Austruy</yazar>
    <tur>Ekonomi</tur>
    <yayınevi>İLGİ YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9944978637</ISBN>
              <tarih>2010-05-31</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Mutlu Evlilik Psikolojisi</isim>
    <yazar>Prof. Dr. Nevzat Tarhan</yazar>
    <tur>Psikoloji</tur>
    <yayınevi>TİMAŞ YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6050822915</ISBN>
              <tarih>2017-11-16</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Mesnevi Terapi</isim>
    <yazar>Prof. Dr. Nevzat Tarhan</yazar>
    <tur>Psikoloji</tur>
    <yayınevi>TİMAŞ YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6050802719</ISBN>
              <tarih>2018-01-16</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Hukukun Temel Kavramları</isim>
    <yazar>Kemal Gözler</yazar>
    <tur>Hukuk</tur>
    <yayınevi>EKİN KİTABEVİ YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6053275015</ISBN>
              <tarih>2017-08-01</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Sofie'nin Dünyası Felsefe Tarihi Üzerine Bir Roman</isim>
    <yazar>Jostein Gaarder</yazar>
    <tur>Felsefe</tur>
    <yayınevi>PAN YAYINCILIK </yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9758434572</ISBN>
              <tarih>2017-02-27</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Prens</isim>
    <yazar>Niccolo Machiavelli</yazar>
    <tur>Felsefe</tur>
    <yayınevi>CAN YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>9750709074</ISBN>
              <tarih>2018-02-09</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Mimar Sinan Mimarideki Osmanlı Mührü</isim>
    <yazar>Yavuz Bahadıroğlu</yazar>
    <tur>Sanat</tur>
    <yayınevi>PANAMA YAYINCILIK</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6055143879</ISBN>
              <tarih>2014-12-18</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Sanat ve Felsefe</isim>
    <yazar>Dücane Cündioğlu</yazar>
    <tur>Sanat</tur>
    <yayınevi>KAPI YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6054683581</ISBN>
              <tarih>2016-11-15</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>İlber Ortaylı Seyahatnamesi</isim>
    <yazar>Prof. Dr. İlber Ortaylı</yazar>
    <tur>Turizm-Gezi</tur>
    <yayınevi>KRONİK KİTAP</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6058301153</ISBN>
              <tarih>2018-03-20</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Alex de Souza</isim>
    <yazar>Marcos Eduardo Neves</yazar>
    <tur>Spor</tur>
    <yayınevi>İNDİGO KİTAP</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6059144742</ISBN>
              <tarih>2017-01-31</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>
```

I cannot get lines between < kitap> and < /kitap> Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.regex.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class kategori {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
File f= new File("/home/ayyuce/Desktop/data/katalog1.xml");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
Scanner s= new Scanner(f);

String txtTur = "<tur>";
String txtTur2 = "</tur>";
String tur;
String turSubS="";
String kitapSubS="";

String txtKitap = "<kitap>";
String txtKitap2 = "</kitap>";
String kitap;

Pattern p;
Matcher m;

ArrayList <String> arrTur= new ArrayList <String>();
ArrayList <String> arrKitap= new ArrayList <String>();

   while(sc.hasNextLine()){
   tur=sc.nextLine();
   p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(txtTur) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(txtTur2));
   m = p.matcher(tur);
   while (m.find()) {
        turSubS= m.group(1);
    arrTur.add(turSubS);    

   }


 }  

   sc.close();


  Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();//tekrarlamalari siler
  hs.addAll(arrTur);
  arrTur.clear();
  arrTur.addAll(hs);

  for(String item :arrTur){
   //System.out.println(item); //item xml dosyasini olustur
  }

  while(s.hasNextLine()){
   kitap=s.nextLine();
   p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(txtKitap) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(txtKitap2));
   m = p.matcher(kitap);
   while (m.find()) {
        kitapSubS= m.group(1);
        arrKitap.add(kitapSubS);    

   }

   }
     s.close();

      for(String item :arrKitap){
       System.out.println(item); 
     }


       }

       }
```

For example Sanat.xml might be:

```
         <kitap>
    <isim>Mimar Sinan Mimarideki Osmanlı Mührü</isim>
    <yazar>Yavuz Bahadıroğlu</yazar>
    <tur>Sanat</tur>
    <yayınevi>PANAMA YAYINCILIK</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6055143879</ISBN>
              <tarih>2014-12-18</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>

<kitap>
    <isim>Sanat ve Felsefe</isim>
    <yazar>Dücane Cündioğlu</yazar>
    <tur>Sanat</tur>
    <yayınevi>KAPI YAYINLARI</yayınevi>
        <detay>
              <ISBN>6054683581</ISBN>
              <tarih>2016-11-15</tarih>
        </detay>
</kitap>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried xpath or xquery?

Comment: That looks like XML. You should parse the file as XML instead of reading it manually. And then you can navigate the XML DOM or use an XSL transformation.

Comment: Thank you so much!